# Cannot delete Flow with error: User (XXXXXXXXXXX) is inactive, so please delete the following flow interviews

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow

**Background**

I am getting this error because a user has left the company:

> Every waiting flow interview has an associated user — the person who
>   caused the interview to start waiting. If that user is inactive, the
>   interviews can't resume.
>
> Theresa May (XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) is inactive, so please delete the
>   following flow interviews

But when I follow their instructions and try and delete the flow I get this error:

```
Database.delete(ID.valueOf('XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'), true);
```

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

**Questions**

1. Why won't it let me delete the Flow?
2. How can I delete the Flow?

Comment: [possibly useful](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_pause_cmp_record.htm). I assume the `XXXXXXXXXX` is the id of a FlowInterview, not a user

Comment: @cropredy I believe it is yes. It's the ID provided by the Salesforce error...